How Can we run jmeter test cases in parallel in regression suite
In my jmeter regression suite. I want to run my test cases in parallel to save overall execution time.
Scenario -

Genrate token GET
Place to orders Post
Run GETs API's to verify all the placed orders

so in the above scenario step 1 and 2  I'm running in a sequential manner i.e.generating tokens and placing orders.
but after placing orders I have multiple APIs to do verification which I want to run parallel to save execution time.
Note - I want to run all the APIs only once as it is my regression suite not used for load testing.

Stuctue of my regssion suite
Test freament
Switch controllet
Include controller --This will take my jmeter cases which will have a transaction controller under which I have put my HTTP request



I have tried a parallel controller.

You can do the following:

Add more users in the Thread Group
Use either multiple If Controllers or Switch Controller so this or that user will execute this(ese) or that request(s)

